# Checking to see if two elements are the same, each element coming from a different string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, bluej

The goal of this code is to compare two different string[] arrays, and check to see how many of the elements match. This will allow the methods to then see whether a student has passed or failed a test, along with determining their letter grade. However, every test done results in true being returned for them passing and an "A" being returned for their letter grade. Now that the elements are being compared correctly, I still have the issue of every element passing the .equals().
i.e. 
`answerKey[1] = "B";
studentAnswers[1] = "C";`
if these two elements were to be compared, it would pass the `.equals().`

```
public class ListOfAnswers
{
    static final String[] answerKey = {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E",
                                       "C", "D", "D", "E", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E"};
    String[] studentAnswers;

    public ListOfAnswers(String[] ans)
    {
        studentAnswers = ans;
    }

    public boolean checkPassOrFail()
    {
        int answersRight = 0;
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < studentAnswers.length; cnt++)
        {
            if(studentAnswers[cnt].equals(answerKey[cnt]))
            {
                answersRight++;
            }
        }
        if (answersRight >= 14)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String computeGrade()
    {
        int score = 0;
        String grade = "";
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < studentAnswers.length; cnt++)
        {
            if (studentAnswers[cnt].(answerKey[cnt]))
            {
                score++;
            }
        }

        if (score < 10)
        {
            grade = "E";
        }
        else if (score == 10)
        {
            grade = "D";
        }
        else if ((score==11)||(score==12))
        {
            grade = "C-";
        }
        else if (score==13)
        {
            grade = "C";
        }
        else if (score == 14)
        {
            grade = "C+";
        }
        else if (score == 15)
        {
            grade = "B-";
        }
        else if (score == 16)
        {
            grade = "B";
        }
        else if (score == 17)
        {
            grade = "B+";
        }
        else if (score == 18)
        {
            grade = "A-";
        }
        else if ((score == 19)||(score==20))
        {
            grade = "A";
        }
        return grade;
    }
}
```

The test data looks as follows

```
public class ListOfAnswersTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] danAnswers = {"A", "B", "B", "D", "D", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "C",
                               "D", "D", "E", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E"};
        ListOfAnswers danAnswerList = new ListOfAnswers(danAnswers);

        String[] bobAnswers = {"A", "C", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "C",
                               "D", "A", "E", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E", "E"};
        ListOfAnswers bobAnswerList = new ListOfAnswers(danAnswers);

        System.out.println("Student Dan's Pass/Fail: " + danAnswerList.checkPassOrFail());
        System.out.println("Student Dan's Grade: " + danAnswerList.computeGrade());

        System.out.println("Student Bob's Pass/Fail: " + bobAnswerList.checkPassOrFail());
        System.out.println("Student Bob's Grade: " + bobAnswerList.computeGrade());
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that no matter what letters you place in the studentAnswers list, the results of both methods come out to be True, and "A". I guess a better question would be if I am comparing the elements of each array correctly in my if statements.

Comment: use studentAnswers[cnt].equals(answerKey[cnt])

Comment: Why are you using array of strings, why not array of chars?

Comment: @BjørnBråthen that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: no, but is it necessary?

Comment: @BjørnBråthen focus on the main problem first.

Comment: already suggested a fix in the comment above.

Comment: @Luiggi I agree, I think I answered something similar yesterday, with the same context.

Comment: @BjørnBråthen, now that the elements are being compared correctly. I'm still having the same problem where no matter if the elements actually do equal each other they still pass the equality test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a typo here:

```
ListOfAnswers bobAnswerList = new ListOfAnswers(danAnswers);
```

should be:

```
ListOfAnswers bobAnswerList = new ListOfAnswers(bobAnswers);
```

or you give the good answers of Dan to Bob ;)

Oh, and as others said, always use `equals` when comparing (non-null) strings unless you really want to check for identity (I see question is already updated to do that).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that was the secondary problem with my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
if(studentAnswers[cnt] == answerKey[cnt])
```

To compare `String`s and other Object instances, you **must** use `equals` method:

```
if(studentAnswers[cnt].equals(answerKey[cnt]))
```

This must be fixed in both methods `ListOfAnswers#checkPassOrFail` and `ListOfAnswers#computeGrade`.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by a second. :)

Comment: the == might still work, as single character string constants might be  "internalized" ... but it is more by accident that they do. However I with that fix I would expect everyone to get a count of zero with the original code ...

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar maybe it's an exercise to show the difference between using `==` and `equals` (since this code looks like homework). Anyway, if you change the test to read the data from an outside source like a file, then the `==` won't work (in this case `String` pooling won't work).

Comment: Thank you for the .equals() fix, but there was also a typo as pointed out.

Comment: Just in case anyone doubts it: I am *not* advocating using '==' with strings - always use equals there unless you really know what you are doing. I just wanted to point out that the problem here might be something else.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar last comment must be part of your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Java when you want to compare objects you must use equal();

```
studentAnswers[cnt] == answerKey[cnt]

studentAnswers[cnt].equals(answerKey[cnt])
```